# Feedback on Experiment: bosses and meetings

Tags: hypothesis-testing, experiment-design

As my context is rather specific, I'll try to write an analogy that sounds more natural and preserves all characteristics of the original problem. It goes like this:

A certain company has around 2k employees. Some of these employees are bosses of other employees. An employee might have several bosses and a boss might be the boss of several employees. Furthermore, if John is Paul's boss and Paul is George's boss, than John is George's boss (i.e., being a boss is a transitive relation). Finally, boss relationships can be created, modified, and removed over time.

Let's say I want to check if, in general, people meet up with their bosses more often than they meet up with non-bosses. Hence, several times a day and for several days, an external person went to all meeting rooms and registered who was there having meetings and what the boss relationships existed at that time. The collected data looks like this:

> ID: #1 Time: July,20th 2015. 2pm. People having meeting: Gloria,
>   Diana, Peter, and Alfred. Boss relationships: Gloria is Peter's boss
>
> ID: #2 Time: July,20th 2015. 2:30pm. People having meeting: Gloria,
>   Steve, and Arnold. Boss relationships: Gloria is Steve's boss, and
>   Steve is Arnold's boss (hence, Gloria is Arnold's boss).
>
> ID: #3 Time: July, 21st 2015. 1:00pm People having meeting: Carl and
>   Maria. Boss relationships: none
>
> ID: #4 Time: July, 21st 2015. 2:00pm People having meeting: Carl (a
>   person might be alone in the meeting room) Boss relationships: none

As stated previously, I want to check if, in general, people meet up more often with their bosses (as compared to non-bosses). More generally, I want to know if the characteristic of "being a boss" influences who meets up with whom. What I did was the following. First, I summarized the data as follows: for every person p that ever participated in a meeting, I created entries `<x_1,p>, <x_2,p>, <x_3,p>, ... <x_n-1, p>`, where `x_i` refers to all employees in the company. For each of these entries, I created the following 4-cell table (which sort of resembles a chi-square table). Every time p was in a meeting, every `<x_i,p>` table got updated. Updating the table means adding one to any of the four cells.

```
Tuple: <x_1,p>
x_1 was in the meeting with p and p is x_1's boss: n1
x_1 was in the meeting with p and p is not x_1's boss: n2
x_1 was NOT in the meeting with p and p is x_1's boss: n3 
x_1 was NOT in the meeting with p and p is NOT x_1's boss: n4
```

After updating all tables with all the data collected, I calculated two metrics for each tuple:

```
MeetingRatioForBoss = n1 / (n1+n3)
MeetingRatioForNonBoss = n2 / (n2+n4)
```

The hypothesis I came up with was: `MeetingRatioForBoss` is higher than `MeetingRatioForNonBoss` in a statistically significant way. As some tuples might not have the two metrics (because of division by zero), I performed the non-parametric, non-paired two-sample Wilcoxon test (a.k.a. Mann Whitney test) with the alternative hypothesis that `MeetingRatioForBoss > MeetingRatioForNonBoss`. Independently of the results I obtained, how does the design of this statistical analysis sound to you guys? Do you see problems with it? Would you have suggestions of alternative/better approaches? Thank you!